# is form button can handle 400 click at the same time?

Tags: timer, click

I am making a site that  who will click button when timer ends first he will won.But I am not sure that if will 400 people will click the same time server can response quickly? And is there will be timer and when timer end click button will be enabled.But is this time will show on each computer as the same time that button enabled? Or  creating this system on flash will be more faster?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.shockingsoft.com/AutoClicker.html?

Answer (score 0):

Your server may not process the requests in the same order they arrived. Also, different clients may have different connection and processing speeds. The first request on the server may not be the first client which clicked the button.

You could measure the time client side, but then the client could easily change the submitted time and cheat.